# REST API - Getting an empty data object in the response

Tags: glympse

While I was developing my app, I used a sandbox API key.
Now that I completed development, I switched to the production API.

The responses I'm getting back from the API all have an empty `data` value:

[image]

This is true for all endpoints that require authentication.
The account/create and account/login endpoints work just fine.

Things I checked so far:

- That correct base url and API token are used
- That the userId and password I'm using are generated by the production API

Is there something else I need to do on my part?

Is there, perhaps, a difference in the API itself, between the sandbox and production environment?

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some problems with your request URL.

Your request URL:
http://api.glympse.com/v2/tickets?invites=true&oauth_token={oauth_token}

Problems:

1) Use https

2) /tickets is an invalid endpoint. I suspect you meant 
https://api.glympse.com/v2/users/self/tickets

3) Don't include token in your URL. Include it in your Authorization header.

4) Never post tokens online! Ever!

Try this...

GET:
https://api.glympse.com/v2/users/self/tickets

HEADER:
Authorization

VALUE:
Bearer pasteyouroauthtokenhere

The Glympse API docs contain a list of most of the endpoints. It isn't 100% up-to-date, but you will find answers to most of your questions: https://admin.enterprise.glympse.com/docs/api

I also suggest connecting with Glympse's development support. They're very responsive and helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
1) Fair enough, I'll try that

2) /tickets is an endpoint documented in the API docs: [link](https://developer.glympse.com/rest/api/tickets) It worked in the sandbox
3) I'll try that too. The only way I was able to login in the sandbox, though,  was by including it in the URL. Also, the REST API samples do that too: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/glympse/pY9vS/)
4) Apologies, slipped my attention

Comment: Also, regarding 2): It's not the only endpoint that returns an empty "data" object. When you say development support, do you mean this [link](https://glympse.zendesk.com/anonymous_requests/new) ?

Comment: Yes, that is the link. There is also a direct email for developer support, but I can't post it on SO.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I followed all you instructions, but the "data" object was still being returned empty. Then I realized that Glympse has a versioned API, and that I'm missing `/v2/` from the base URL.. :) Appended it, and the problem went away.

Comment: Good catch. Thank you. I updated my response appropriately.